# Editing Dreamweaver Hotkey/shorcuts

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I am trying to change the hot key for collapse full tag which defaults as <kbd>ctrl+shift+j</kbd>. Where can I locate it in the keyboard shorcuts menu to change it?

Answer (score 0):

[Dreamweaver Keyboard Shortcuts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7764a.html)?

> Edit an existing shortcut
>
> ```
> Select Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts (Windows) or Dreamweaver > Keyboard Shortcuts (Macintosh).
> From the Commands pop‑up menu, select a command category.
> In the Commands list, select a command and then select a shortcut to change.
> Click in the Press Key and enter a new key combination.
> Click the Change button to change the shortcut.
> Note: If there is a problem with the key combination (for example, if the key combination 
> is already assigned to another command), an
> explanatory message appears just below the Shortcuts field and you may
> be unable to add or edit the shortcut.
> ```

Comment: I guess what I was trying to ask is where in the commands list is the Collapse Full Tag?

Comment: That command specifically is under the Menu Commands option, Edit -> Code Collapse